# How can I update a dashing widget's refresh frequency?

Tags: dashing

I'm current using Dashing for displaying dashboards on our office TVs. By default each of our widgets gets refreshed every 60 seconds.

I actually would like to change this to 30 seconds. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at each widgets associated .rb file, you should find something similar to this (taken from my news.rb). note '60m' is 1-hr.  In your file change it to '30s'

```
SCHEDULER.every '60m', :first_in => 0 do |job|
@News.each do |news|
headlines = news.latest_headlines()
send_event(news.widget_id, { :headlines => headlines })
```